# ConTeXt: How do a \hrule beneath title in grid mode?

Tags: context, grid-typesetting

How can I place the \hrule beneath the title in grid mode the same as in grid mode off? Why is the \hrule more greyish in grid mode?

Grid off:

```
\setuplayout[grid=off]
\setuphead[title][after=\hrule, page=no]

\starttext
\starttitle[title={Title}]
Lorem ipsum
\stoptitle
\stoptext
```

[image]

Grid on:

[image]

Comment: So you effectively want an out-of-grid element after the section title?

Comment: The greyish rule is very likely a rendering issue.  Does it persist when you print the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking.  Is this what you are looking for?

```
\setuplayout[grid=on]

\define[1]\RuledTitle{#1\hrule}

\setuphead
  [title]
  [textcommand=\RuledTitle,
   page=no]

\showgrid
\starttext

\starttitle[title={Title}]
  Lorem ipsum
\stoptitle

\stoptext
```

[image]